# Add additional path to exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I would like to add an additional class path to the exec-maven-plugin.
Besides the %classpath, I would like to add an extra path to a directory containing resources (/Users/kornp/resources).
Currently, my pom looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <classpathScope>runtime</classpathScope>
    <arguments>
      <argument>%classpath:/Users/kornp/resources</argument>
      <argument>org.drrabbit.maventest.App</argument>
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How should I configure this?

Answer (score 5):

I have some configuration files in a specific directory outside of my source folder. So i defined additonal resources to my pom.xml file.

my sample directory structure is:

```
+ src
+ conf
  - app.properties
  - log4j.xml
- pom.xml
```

my pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>conf</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>

  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <mainClass>com.mycompany.MyMainClass</mainClass>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
<build>
```

Now we may execute the program:

```
mvn clean compile exec:java
```

Comment: i have a problem getting this to work in the case where my main class comes from a dependency and not the project itself.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using the [`commandlineArgs`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#commandlineArgs) parameter (as mentioned in the [exec example](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html))?

Comment: @Kornp Arf, sorry then, that was not my understanding of the example. I don't know if there is another way though. Is setting the classpath manually an option?

Comment: Yes, it's an option, but there are quite a lot of jar files involved. So, it will be a tedious job.
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Though it looks less elegant, but switching to antrun plugin should works:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>runSomething</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>

                    <java classname="org.drrabbit.maventest.App" 
                            fork="true" 
                            failonerror="true" 
                            maxmemory="512m">

                        <classpath>
                            <pathelement path="${project.build.directory}/some/extra/resources" />
                            <pathelement path="${runtime_classpath}" />
                        </classpath>
                    </java>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, it doesn't seems a good idea to have the extra resources put in somewhere outside the project, as your op suggested.  You should either consider putting that as part of the project, or make it a jar and deploy to maven repo so you can put it as a plugin dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I adapted the plugin so that the command line arguments can be fully specified (including the %classpath parameter)

Comment: If you care to copy the result into the answer you might eventualy get the 3 up votes for the self learner badge.

Comment: Martin, what do you mean with copy the result into the answer?

Comment: @KornP, where is your adapted plugin?

Comment: @KornP please provide an answer, i have the same problem and would actually like to know how you solved it.