# Add maven's output directory to exec:java classpath

Tags: maven, configuration, resources, pom.xml

I want to add the `target/classes` directory to maven's `exec:java` classpath. The compilation and runtime dependencies are handled fine, but the resources copied from `src/*/resources` are not available during execution. I am almost sure it is because the plugins' classpath includes only the project dependencies and not the `target/classes` directory. I'd like to be able to run the application during development as `mvn clean compile exec:java`
while leaving all properties files, and other files in the resources directories.

I've tried several variations of exec configuration but I can't seem to get it right:

my pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <mainClass>Example</mainClass>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-cp</argument>
        <classpath/>
        <argument>%classpath:target/classes</argument>

        <argument>someFile.txt</argument>
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't think this one is correct syntax because I'm getting an ArrayStoreException:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2763)
at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:305)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ArrayConverter.fromConfiguration(ArrayConverter.java:141)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.ComponentValueSetter.configure(ComponentValueSetter.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:137)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultPluginManager.java:1357)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:724)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.jav
```

I used example configuration poms from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587935/add-additional-path-to-exec-maven-plugin/12495150#12495150) and [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `target/classes` and all the dependencies are in the `classpath` when you use `exec-maven-plugin` plugin.

I have similar setup and following config works for me. In my `Test` class I read one xml file as `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mapping.xml")`. I have kept the file in `src/main/resources` which after build is available under `target/classes`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <mainClass>com.Test</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: i was using `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getSystemResourceAsStream("...");` and changing it to Thread... fixed the problem.

Comment: `mainClass` is a configuration option for the `java` goal, not the `exec` goal. For `exec`, the main class should be passed within `<arguments><argument>com.Test</argument></arguments>`, which are passed to the `java` executable. `mainClass` is ignored in the `exec` goal.